# Insert a value in a numpy array column and keep the same size / row values

Tags: python, numpy

The title is not the best but essentially I need to insert a value at (y,x) and shift the column until -1 is met where I insert a new value and delete -1. Here is an example to insert (100) at (2,1):

```
b = np.array([[1,-1,3],
     [2,5,6],
     [6,8,9],
     [10,4,3])
```

would become:

```
b = np.array([[1,5,3],
     [2,8,6],
     [6,100,9],
     [10,4,3]])
```

This example is for a case where I need to insert at a column but eventually I'll have to do it for rows as well. Numpy arrays may not be the best DS for this so if you have a better idea, dont hesitate. Thank you!

Comment: `b` is a list, not an numpy array.

Comment: @hpaulj My bad, edited the post to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's import numpy and define your array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.array([[1,-1,3], [2,5,6], [6,8,9], [10,4,3]])
```

Now, to do your substitution, try:

```
>>> b[:, 1] = np.concatenate((b[1:3, 1], [100], b[3:, 1]))
>>> b
array([[  1,   5,   3],
       [  2,   8,   6],
       [  6, 100,   9],
       [ 10,   4,   3]])
```

Comment: I modified your solution a little bit to get it to work for any position of -1. Thank you!    l3[:, 1] = np.concatenate((l3[:idy, 1], [100], l3[idy+1:, 1])).   where idy is the index of -1  `code in backticks`